# Change src of script from bower_components to cdn though gulp

Tags: html, node.js, optimization, gulp, cdn

I have some scripts tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" cdn="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js" cdn="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
```

which I want to change to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
```

I've tried cdnify but we have to code everything in gulp itself.
I want more control from HTML file itself, so it will be easy to control if I am using different cdn urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize [`gulp-replace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to alter your html files, and use a regex `/src="(.+?)"\scdn="(.+?)"/gmi`

This should work:

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('replace-cdn', function(){
  gulp.src(['index.html'])
    .pipe(replace(/src="(.+?)"\scdn="(.+?)"/gmi, 'src="$2"'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build '));
});
```

Comment: Even for scripts without **cdn** attribute it preserved its orignal. Thank you :)